# how to fill the values in numpy to create a Spectrum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have done the following code but do not understand properly what is going on there.
Can anyone explain how to fill colors in Numpy?

Also I want to set in values in a way from `1 to 0` to give spectrum an intensity. E.g-: 0 means low intensity, 1 means high intensity

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

a= np.zeros([256*6,256*6, 3], dtype=np.uint8) # init the array
# fill the array with rgb values to create the spectrum without the use of loops

#red
a[:,:,0] = np.concatenate(([255]*256, np.linspace(255,0,256), [0]*256, [0]*256, np.linspace(0,255,256), [255]*256))

#green
a[:,:,1] = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0,255,256), [255]*256, [255]*256, np.linspace(255,0,256), [0]*256,[0]*256))

#blue
a[:,:,2] = np.concatenate(([0]*256, [0]*256,np.linspace(0,255,256),[255]*256, [255]*256, np.linspace(255,0,256)))


plt.imshow(a)  # this is different than what I am looking for
```

Expected Output-:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Print the `a` and `a.shape` after each line. You will see what is happening. Btw you should know the concept of color and `RGB` to see what's happening there.

Comment: @MSH Thanks! Shape remains the same, and it is hard to visualize the values of a. could you help me with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
res=256
op=np.zeros([res,res, 3]) # init the array

#RGB

op[:,:,0]= np.linspace(0,1,res)

op[:,:,1]=np.linspace(0,1,res).reshape (256, 1)

op[:,:,2]= np.linspace(1,0,res)

plt.imshow(op)
```

it will give the exact thing that you are looking for!

let me know if it does not work

Answer (score 7):

First of all:
The results here when I tried the code is different then what you displayed in the question.

[image: The result image]

### Color

#### Monochromatic

Let's say we have a gray scaled picture. Each pixel would have a value of `integers` between [0, 255]. Sometimes these values can be `floats` between [0, 1].

Here `0` is black and `255` is white. The vales between (0, 255) are grays. Towards `0` it gets more gray, towards `255` its less gray.

#### Polychromatic

(I'm not sure about the term Polychromatic)
Colored pixels are not so different then gray scaled ones. The only different is colored pixels storing `3` different values between [0, 255] for each `Red`, `Green` and `Blue` values.

[image: Colors]

see: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-additive-model-of-RGB-Red-green-and-blue-are-the-primary-stimuli-for-human-colour_fig2_328189604

Now let's see what what the image you are creating is like:

#### Creation:

You are crating a matrix of zeros with shape of: `256, 256 * 6, 3`, which is: `256, 1536, 3`.

#### R values

Then with the first line you are replacing the first column with something else:

```
a[:, :, 0] = np.concatenate(
    (
        [255] * 256,
        np.linspace(255, 0, 256),
        [0] * 256,
        [0] * 256,
        np.linspace(0, 255, 256),
        [255] * 256
    )
)
```

Lets see what this lines do:

`np.concatenate` is easy. It meregs the arrays give.
What are the given arrays?

1. [255] * 256

It is an array full of `255`s with length of 256:

`[255, 255, ..., 255, 255]`

2. `np.linspace(255, 0, 256)`

It is 256 values between [255, 0].:

`[255, 254, 253, .., 2, 1, 0]`

3. `[0] * 256`

See 1

4. `[0] * 256`

See 1

5. `np.linspace(0, 255, 256)`

The reverse of 2. See 2.

6. `[255] * 256`

See 1

#### G and B Values

You can follow the same logic for `Green` and ,Blue,

Let's see how these values are changing by plotting them.

The matrix `a` has the same value along y axis. So if we could plot `R`, `G` and `B`  values of one line of the matrix. We can see how the values are changing:

```
plt.plot(a[0][:, 0], "r-", label="Red values along x axis")
plt.plot(a[0][:, 1], "g-", label="Green values along x axis")
plt.plot(a[0][:, 2], "b-", label="Blue values along x axis")


plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image: Values of R, G and Bs of a line on matrix a]

Comment: yes, i forget to put the output of the code. I just posted my expected output. Thanks for this information, could you guide me with what should I do in order to get the Expected result? , if you know the different approach, let me know!

Comment: I tried really hard to make sure I covered everything. Now you are asking how to achieve the circular color pallet. With all due respect, it looks like you are not trying to understand but to have the job done.I only can tell you that you need radial gradient.

Comment: I am still working on this! I am getting different kind of outputs. Question is also about how to get expected output. but thanks for your time, I am still working on it. hopefully, if i solve it, then will post the answer here